# Weird bug in Chrome / Javascript http response

Tags: javascript, laravel, google-chrome, firefox, microsoft-edge

I have this application with a builder for customer emails. They have the option to insert images and much more.

The image uploader post to a Laravel function that uploads the image to AWS s3 and returns the location & url.

The problem arises whenever a user tries to upload an image in Chrome.
The response has a div-element attached to it, which can be seen below

```
{"url":"some-url","location":"some-location"}<div style="width: 350px; top: -600px; right: 0px; padding: 0px; position: fixed; z-index: 0; visibility: hidden; transition: all 0.5s ease 0s; overflow: hidden;"></div>
```

When I do the same thing in edge / firefox the response looks like this:

```
Object { url: "some-url", location: "some-location" }
```

I then have to handle it in javascript by using the split() function to remove the div.
My current solution to the problem looks like this in JS:

```
            if(typeof response === "object"){
                result = response;
            }
            else {
                result = JSON.parse(response.split('<div')[0]);
            }
```

It seems like a weird bug with Chrome since it works perfectly fine in firefox / edge.

Has anyone experienced something like this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that something is appending the div to your response and that FireFox is doing some extra work to handle it that Chrome isn't doing.

But ask yourself, what can we infer from the div itself to determine what might be causing the issue? It's position: fixed and off the top of the right side of the page. So, it's probably a notification confirming the upload.

Investigate the section of your code that handles success notifications.